# Colors in Emacs shell prompt

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to use colors in the Emacs shell prompt (the prompt itself, not the rest of the shell screen) with the bash PS1 variable?  I believe I have the syntax correct (e.g., `PS1='[\u@\h \[\e[0;31m\]\W\[\e[m\]]\$ '` - it works in term or ansi-term), but it seems like Emacs is applying the comint-highlight-prompt face.  I can set that to some color, and it works, but I want to be able to set individual parts of the prompt to different colors.  I prefer using shell over term or ansi-term, so I'd rather not switch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out:  The `comint-highlight-prompt` face was set to inherit from `minibuffer-prompt`, which was setting the `:weight`, `:foreground` and `:background`.  Removing the inheritance prevented the colors set in `PS1` from being overridden by the `comint-highlight-prompt` face.  Added this to my `.emacs` file.

```
(set-face-attribute 'comint-highlight-prompt nil
                    :inherit nil)
```

Also, `M-x customize-group <ret> font-lock-faces` was helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: That will not work in Ubuntu 16.04 that uses Emacs 24.5 due to Emacs bug https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20084 that has already been fixed on git://git.sv.gnu.org/emacs.git at commit 792d44b3c31d2a682607ab8b79ae7d26b7402f41. To make your solution work, use https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html with "comint" to fix "comint-snapshot-last-prompt" and "comint-output-filter" and with "font-lock" to add "font-lock--remove-face-from-text-property".

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend not to change the face globally (since there are many comint users besides shell mode) but in a buffer specific manner by setting a mode hook:

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (face-remap-set-base 'comint-highlight-prompt :inherit nil)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use that to change the terminal color and the information in mac, maybe can help:

```
Cyan="$(tput setaf 6)"
NC="$(tput sgr0)" # No Color
export PS1="$Cyan.Where-> \w\n\\$\[$NC\]"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still gets set to the comint-highlight-prompt face.  I have tried doing `(set-face-foreground 'comint-highlight-prompt nil)` in my .emacs file, but the prompt still gets set to all cyan.